The Element Quality Team wants our feedback
The following was posted on the LEGO Ambassador Network yesterday:

The Element Quality Team reached out to us [the Community team]
  because they realize that AFOLs use LEGO elements in new and creative
  ways and if there is a concern it is likely that a member of your
  community could find it.
Please continue to report set specific errors to LEGO Consumer
  Services but if your community finds an element concern or element
  limitation post your concern here and we will make sure it is passed
  on to the Element Quality Team!
We will consistently share your community member’s feedback with the
  team which could create follow up steps like the request for pictures
  or videos and we will share any feedback the Element Quality Team
  provides.

This represents a welcome change giving us a more direct channel to report quality issues with elements. I'll report any specific issues that come up organically in questions here, but if you have noticed anything specific that you believe would be helpful to share with the team now, feel free to let me know.
